# Laravel v3.2.13-5 blade templating doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3, laravel-blade

I'm new at laravel but I found something very strange.

In my blade template I wrote:

```
@if( $appModule == 'someting' ) 
     Something
@elseif($appModule == 'somethingelse')
     SomethingElse
@else 
      Nothing 
@endif
```

When I run I get an error:

> Unhandled Exception
>
> Message:
>
> Error rendering view: [layout]
>
> syntax error, unexpected '?'
>   Location:
>
> ...\storage\views/a5d6961979ebea7e1177c3836de35dd8 on line 41

I opened 'a5d6961979ebea7e1177c3836de35dd8' and found this:

```
<?php if( $appModule == 'someting' ) Something <?php else: ?>if($appModule == 'somethingelse'): ?> SomethingElse <?php else: ?> Nothing <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "`a5d6961979ebea7e1177c3836de35dd8`" file is just the blade rendered PHP version of your view file. The error itself is in your view file.

I noticed you typed:

```
@if( $appModule == 'someting' )
```

Shouldnt that be

```
@if( $appModule == 'something' )
```

Comment: the error is here: "<?php if( $appModule == 'someting' ) Something <?php else: ?>if" and I don't understand why blade doesn't compile right...

Comment: yeah - i noticed that - perhaps it is being caused by code elsewhere in your view. what happens if you have a view with JUST the IF statement? does it compile correctly?

Comment: I have just tried and I noticed that if I have only \@if \@endif everything is ok, but if I have \@if \@elseif \@endif it causes an error!

Comment: Sounds like a bug - perhaps try an earlier version of laravel - 3.2.5 or something...

Comment: Having a very similar with a view and an \@if \@elseif statement, only happens to me when using a translation though {{ _('string.tranlsation') }}. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert (or create a new) file `layout.blade.php`, to the following Format/Encoding: `UNIX/ANSI`